# Need to Set the Map in Layout to fit completely to a layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, extents, layouts, mapping, qgis-print-layouts

So, I know that there is the "Set to map canvas extend" but it just doesn't do the job for me. I used ArcGIS more than QGIS so I am having issues accomodating to the map layout options in QGIS. I want to set the map layout completely to a specific polygon layer that encapsulates the project area. I use QGIS 3.10.

[image: Desired map area]

However, when I zoom to layer and "Set to map canvas extend", I get a different outcome:

[image: The outcome]

Now, I am looking to have the lines of the map extend completely fit the polygon extend. How can I accomplish this? So, at the end, I want the grid (blue-white) to be as a border.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have two options. First, you can adjust the borders of the grid blue-white to fit with the polygon since you are using a square polygon and a rectangle. Second, you can zoom in on your qgis map (not the layout) untill you reach the right position. Then use the button as in the screenshot. To be honest ArcGIS is much more to the point than the QGIS layouts. It is really a trail and error process.

I did this with QGIS 3.10.5.

At 1: You can add a map

At 2: You can see how big your map is. make it square

At 3: You go t item properties when selecting the map

At 4: You see several options to edit the map extent

At 5: Here you can manually edit the extent of your map.

[image]

Comment: Hi @GISGUILD. I don't have that button as you on the screenshot which is quite strange. I am using QGIS 3.10. Anyway, it really seems silly that they haven't thought about resolving such minor issues which mean a lot for map design.

Comment: As for the first part, how can I adjust the grid to fit the polygon?

Comment: Would the best way be to actually take the 4 coordinates from the corners and just manually input that as extents?

Comment: Since the area is 4x4 km, can I make the map layout 4x4 km somehow?

Comment: @Matija, I used QGIS 3.10.5 for the example. In deed it is a good option to take the four coordinates and to manually add the extents. You can make the map 4x4 when you click in the layout on the map. just give it a square dimension and you will be fine.

Comment: I think this is quite easy to accomplish this. On the extents you need to use data defined and use an expression that takes the corner coordinates of the polygon

Comment: Can you enlighten us then with the specific expression?

Comment: This will also be affected by the scale at which you are visualizing your polygon. But you could try the following. In the properties of your map assign it an ITEM ID ie map and using the extent make sure that you use data defined for each of the four options x_min etc. Use an expression like x_min( map_get(item_variables('map'), 'map_extent')). Also change the scale to be reasonable